# The equidistant set of a closed set 1

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\geq2$. For $r>0$, let $F_r$ be the set of points $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that dist($x,F)=r$ (distance between $x$ and $F$). Notice that if $F$ is not connected, then $F_r$ mais also be disconnected. Now suppose for some $r>0$, the set $F_r$ has a bounded component; that is for some $R>0$ a component of $F_r$ is contained in the ball centered at the origin with  radius $R$. This is clear from a picture that then for all $0<\rho<r$ the set $F_\rho$ has also a bounded component. But how would you  prove this?

Comment: Well, this is actually false already for (some) closed subsets of $R^2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: could you tell us more please.

Comment: Hint: Take $A$ which is the complement to the interval $I=(-1,1)$ in the $x$-axis. Take a circle $C$ containing the end-points $p,q$ of of the interval $I$ and whose radius is sufficiently large. Let $B$ denote $C$ minus the shorter arc of $C$ between $p, q$. Now, take $F$ which is the union $A\cup B$. (Note that $F$ is connected.) Take $r=1+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small. Then $F_r$ will be disconnected but have one bounded component (and two unbounded ones). On the other hand, for $r\le 1$, both components of $F_r$ are unbounded.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: that looks very plausible to me. Why not write it up as an answer?

Comment: @RobArthan I might. But I would not want to do the calculations, they are quite messy. The example is quite standard "in my neck of the woods."

Comment: @MoisheKohan: perhaps you could post a picture.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly a simplified version of the counterexample given by Moishe Kohan in the comments - my contribution is just illustrating it and choosing nice coordinates that make computation easy.

---

This is false. Consider the set $F\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ consisting of the union of:

- A closed ray $(x,0)$ for $x\geq 1$.
- Line segments connecting $(1,0)$ to $(1,-1)$ to $(-1, -1)$ to $(-1, 1)$ to $(0,1)$.
- A closed ray $(0,y)$ for $y\geq 1$.

[image: An image depicting S.]

It can be readily observed that $\{(0,0)\}$ is a connected component of $F_1$ - and, indeed, is the only point of $F_1$ within $(-1,1)\times (-1,1)$. More generally, $F_r$ has a bounded component whenever $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < r \leq 1$.

We can see this visually, illustrated at an $r$ slightly less than $1$ for more clarity:

[image: An image of F_r for r slightly less than 1.]

However, if $r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we can describe $F_r$ as two unbounded components, consisting of line segments, rays, and circular arcs - though I'll leave the precise listing and verification of this claim to the reader, as it's entirely a mechanical proof. The set $F_r$ would be as illustrated in the following picture:

[image: An image of F_r for small r.]

The fact that $F_1$ has a bounded component but $F_{1/2}$ does not contradicts your desired theorem.

Answer (score 1):

How would I prove it?

**Lemma 1.** $F\subseteq(F_r)_r$.

**Lemma 2.** If $F_r=\bigsqcup_j{A^j}$ is a decomposition into connected components, let $B^j=A^j_r\cap F$.  Then each $B^j$ is relatively clopen and $F=\bigsqcup_j{B^j}$.

**Lemma 3.** With the same notation, $A^j$ is bounded iff $B^j$ is.  (Use Lemma 1.)

**Lemma 4.** With the same notation, $F_{\rho}=\bigcup_j{B^j_{\rho}}$, and each $B^j_{\rho}$ is relatively closed.

**Lemma 5.** When $\rho<r$, the decomposition in Lemma 4 is disjoint.

I leave the proofs (and how to apply Lemmas 3 & 5 to your problem) to you.

These lemmas apply in any metric space, not just $\mathbb{R}^{\geq2}$, although they get a little tricky to apply to your problem in the discrete metric space….

Answer (score 1):

Let $0< \rho <r.$ Let $F_r$ has a bounded component $C_r \subseteq F_r$. From the definition of $F_r$ it is clear that $0<\rho <r \implies diam(C_\rho)<diam(C_r),$ hence $C_{\rho}$ are bounded for any $\rho \in (0,r).$

Note that $C_\rho$ might be one of many components which is a subset of the closet set bounded by $C_r.$